# Hyperledger fabric transactions disk usage

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I need your help. Please, explain to me how to calculate disk space usage if we have 100k transactions per day and each transaction size is 4 kb. I need to calculate disk usage for 1 year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few peaces of information missing in order to help you with calculation. Basically need to know how many organizations is going to be in your network and what would be the endorsement policy. And the reason for that is because each transaction includes certificates of the corresponding endorsing peers, used later to check whenever endorsement policy is satisfied. Size of each certificate roughly 3Kb.

**For example**: if you have 10 organizations and your endorsement policy is majority, hence each transaction has to be endorsed by 6, meaning you need to include 6 certs -> 18Kb need to be added to your initial 22Kb. Per day it will be 22Kb * 100K = 2.2GB, and overall per year 2.2GB * 365 = 800GB.

Please note this doesn't consider the state database, since it really depends on what exactly you going to store/update, but it will be same order of magnitude as your ledger (more or less), hence to conclude this sizing exercise I'd say you can approximately expect something like 2Tb (this example only).

**NOTE**, this is only an example on how you can do such sizing, while I'd strongly encourage to run an experimental testing to count for real numbers.

Comment: Thank you for thorough answer, can you also answer if it's possible to ziping blocks to decrease disk space usage ?

Comment: No, this is not possible

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand what you mean by "but it will be same order of magnitude as your ledger". I understand it like that the CouchDB (let's say my state database) has the current world state (not the entire chain of txs.) then how could its size reach comparable to actual ledger size?